# What is happening with this chain of Promises?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, es6-promise

I am scratching my head trying to understand what is happening with the following cases.

Case 1:

```js
async function doSomething(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {

        const promise = (async () => "A")();

        promise
            .then(() => {
                console.log("THEN");
                resolve();
            })
            .catch(() => {
                console.log("CATCH");
            })
            .finally(() => {
                console.log("FINALLY");
            });
    });
}

async function main() {
    await doSomething();
    console.log("DONE");
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Output, as expected:

```
THEN
FINALLY
DONE
```

But in case 2:

```js
async function doSomething(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {

        const promise = (async () => Promise.resolve("A"))();

        promise
            .then(() => {
                console.log("THEN");
                resolve();
            })
            .catch(() => {
                console.log("CATCH");
            })
            .finally(() => {
                console.log("FINALLY");
            });
    });
}

async function main() {
    await doSomething();
    console.log("DONE");
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

The output is:

```
THEN
DONE
FINALLY
```

And case 3:

```js
async function doSomething(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {

        const promise = (async () => Promise.resolve("A"))();

        promise
            .then(() => {
                console.log("THEN");
                resolve();
            })
            .finally(() => {
                console.log("FINALLY");
            });
    });
}

async function main() {
    await doSomething();
    console.log("DONE");
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

The output is:

```
THEN
FINALLY
DONE
```

What is happening exactly to the chain of promises?

Why the case 2 doesn't print "THEN, FINALLY, DONE"?

Why the case 3 behaves differently from case 2?

Comment: your mixing promises and async, don't do that. Pick one or the other

Comment: Your also using the [explicit constructor promise anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). If you get rid of these two things your code will be much easier to understand

Comment: It's really not clear what your asking. Why is it doing that? Because that's how promises work?

Comment: @Liam is right. Basically, I think the async-with-no-await behaves like a fire-and-forget, so should be like starting two threads (if it was a multithread framework) in parallel.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I know that the code of the cases is wrong/incorrect/unclear, but I am curious to know what is happening with this dirty code :)

Comment: Well, not really. JS is (mostly) single threaded.

Comment: What the OP is trying to ask is why does a `.catch` block affects the order of execution.

Comment: @Liam _"It's really not clear what your asking. Why is it doing that?"_ - The only difference between example 1 and 2 is the use of `Promise.resolve()` in the `async` function. So why is the output different two the one from example 1?

Comment: You have to get rid of the `async` in the second and third case

Comment: @Nullable And why? This won't change anything as this only indicates that the return value of that function is a `Promise`. And that's the case in all three examples. Only difference is ex 1 with an implicit `Promise`

Comment: The high level explanation is when you put more promises in the chain or promises that resolve differently, it can influence the relative timing vs. other things (more or differently timed trips through the event loop).  As others have said, this code is a total mess and it is not worth diagnosing in detail because it's not a real world situation at all with no real asynchronous operations and a bunch of anti-pattern code structures.  Sequencing of real world code is driven by the timing of actual asynchronous operations completing, not artificial do-nothing promises.

Answer (score 0):

I might have understood what happened with the 3 cases.

##### TLDR

The difference in number of promises and the resolution of promises with promise changes the sequence of microtask enqueued causing the difference in print statements.

##### Code simplification

First of all lets try to simplify the code removing the async/await. I will use the code of case 1 for the simplification.

The main block

```
async function doSomething(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        ...
    });
}
async function main() {
    await doSomething();
    console.log("DONE");
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

can be rewrote to:

```
function doSomething(): Promise<void> {
   // Promise A
   return new Promise(resolve => {
     // Promise B
     const b = new Promise(resolve => {
            ...
     });
     resolve(b);
   });
}

doSomething()
 .then(function externalThen() {
   console.log("DONE");
 });
```

The `promise` declaration for case 1:

```
const promise = (async () => "A")();
```

becomes:

```
const promise = Promise.resolve("A");
```

and for case 2 and 3:

```
const promise = (async () => Promise.resolve("A"))();
```

becomes:

```
const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
         resolve(Promise.resolve("A"))
});
```

Putting all together and removing unnecessary functions and variable declarations:

```
// Promise A
new Promise(resolve => {
    // Promise B
    const b = new Promise<void>(resolve => {
        // Promise C
        new Promise(resolve => {
            resolve("A");
        })
        .then(function then1() {
            console.log("THEN");
            resolve();
        })
        .catch(function catch1() {
            console.log("CATCH");
        })
        .finally(function finally1() {
            console.log("FINALLY");
        });
    });
    resolve(b);
})
.then(function externalThen() {
    console.log("DONE");
});
```

For case 2 and 3 the Promise C declaration becomes:

```
// Promise C
new Promise(resolve => {
    // Promise D
    resolve(Promise.resolve("A"));
})
```

##### How Promise code is executed

- the executor function passed to the Promise constructor is executed immediately.
- the callbacks passed to `then`, `catch` and `finally` methods are executed as microtask when the promise fulffils.
- microtask are enqueue in a microtask queue
- the microtask queue is emptied and all the tasks executed, in FIFO order, when the JS stack is empty
- passing a Promise `p1` to the `resolve` callback of a Promise `p2` generates a new microtask that chains `p1` to `p2`. The `then` method of `p1` is called passing the `resolve` and `reject` callbacks of `p2`.

##### Execution case 1

```
// Promise A
new Promise(resolve => {
    // Promise B
    const b = new Promise<void>(resolve => {
        // Promise C
        new Promise(resolve => {
            resolve("A");
        })
        .then(function then1() {
            console.log("THEN");
            resolve();
        })
        .catch(function catch1() {
            console.log("CATCH");
        })
        .finally(function finally1() {
            console.log("FINALLY");
        });
    });
    resolve(b);
})
.then(function externalThen() {
    console.log("DONE");
});
```

1. execution traverse the Promise constructors for Promise A, B and C
2. C is resolved immediately
3. the execution of callback `then1` is added in the microtask queue
4. execution continues chaining promises until `resolve(b)`
5. `b` is a Promise that is passed as resolve value for Promise A. This generates a new microtask that chains B to A.
6. End of main block, two microtasks in the queue: `then1`, `chain-B-to-A`.
7. execution of `then1`:

   1. prints in console **"THEN"**
   2. resolves Promise `b`
   3. the Promise generated by `then` resolves and enqueues a microtask for `catch1`
8. execution of `chain-B-to-A`:

   1. in pseudo code: `b.then(a.resolve, a.reject)`
   2. the Promise B is already resolved therefore the microtask `then-B-A` is enqueued
9. microtask queue a this moment: `catch`, `then-B-A`
10. execution of `catch1`:

    1. nothing to do with the callback
    2. the Promise generated by catch resolves and enqueues a microtask for `finally1`
11. execution of `then-B-A`:

    1. Promise A resolves and enqueues a microtask for `externalThen`
12. microtask queue a this moment: `finally1`, `externalThen`
13. execution of `finally1`: prints **"FINALLY"**
14. execution of `externalThen`: prints **"DONE"**
15. no more microtaks, code terminates

##### Execution case 2

```
// Promise A
new Promise(resolve => {
    // Promise B
    const b = new Promise<void>(resolve => {
        // Promise C
        new Promise(resolve => {
           // Promise D
           resolve(Promise.resolve("A"));
        })
        .then(function then1() {
            console.log("THEN");
            resolve();
        })
        .catch(function catch1() {
            console.log("CATCH");
        })
        .finally(function finally1() {
            console.log("FINALLY");
        });
    });
    resolve(b);
})
.then(function externalThen() {
    console.log("DONE");
});
```

1. execution traverse the Promise constructors for Promise A, B and C
2. Promise C is resolved with Promise D, this generates a microtask to chain  D to C
3. execution continues chaining promises until `resolve(b)`
4. `b` is a Promise that is passed as resolve value for Promise A. This generates a new microtask that chains B to A.
5. End of main block, two microtasks in the queue: `chain-D-to-C`, `chain-B-to-A`.
6. execution of `chain-D-to-C`:

   1. in pseudo code: `d.then(c.resolve, c.reject)`
   2. the microtask `then1` is enqueued
7. execution of `chain-B-to-A`:

   1. in pseudo code: `b.then(a.resolve, a.reject)`
   2. Promise B is not resolved, nothing else happens
8. microtask queue a this moment: `then1`
9. execution of `then1`:

   1. prints in console **"THEN"**
   2. resolves Promise `b`, this enqueues the `then-B-A` microtask
   3. the Promise generated by `then` resolves and enqueues a microtask for `catch1`
10. microtask queue a this moment: `then-B-A`, `catch1`
11. execution of `then-B-A`:

    1. Promise A resolves and enqueues a microtask for `externalThen`
12. execution of `catch1`:

    1. nothing to do with the callback
    2. the Promise generated by catch resolves and enqueues a microtask for `finally1`
13. microtask queue a this moment: `externalThen`, `finally1`
14. execution of `externalThen`: prints **"DONE"**
15. execution of `finally1`: prints **"FINALLY"**
16. no more microtaks, code terminates

##### Execution case 3

```
// Promise A
new Promise(resolve => {
    // Promise B
    const b = new Promise<void>(resolve => {
        // Promise C
        new Promise(resolve => {
           // Promise D
           resolve(Promise.resolve("A"));
        })
        .then(function then1() {
            console.log("THEN");
            resolve();
        })
        .finally(function finally1() {
            console.log("FINALLY");
        });
    });
    resolve(b);
})
.then(function externalThen() {
    console.log("DONE");
});
```

All identical to case 2 until here:

8. microtask queue a this moment: `then1`
9. execution of `then1`:

   1. prints in console **"THEN"**
   2. resolves Promise `b`, this enqueues the `then-B-A` microtask
   3. the Promise generated by `then` resolves and enqueues a microtask for `finally1`
10. microtask queue a this moment: `then-B-A`, `finally1`
11. execution of `then-B-A`:

    1. Promise A resolves and enqueues a microtask for `externalThen`
12. execution of `finally1`: prints **"FINALLY"**
13. microtask queue a this moment: `externalThen`
14. execution of `externalThen`: prints **"DONE"**
15. no more microtaks, code terminates